# update specific array in DataArray

Tags: python, pandas, python-xarray

I have a (4,6,3) dimensional DataArray. I want to update particular rows and columns.

Lets say I want to update first row of n1  [18,  4, 81] to [0,0,0] and update last column of n4 [15,20,31,91,27,39] to [1,1,1,1,1,1].  Please show how to?

```
tmp=xr.DataArray(np.random.randint(99,size=(4,6,3)), coords={'sample':['n1','n2','n3','n4'],'delta':['dx','dy','dz']}, dims=('sample','y','delta'))
<xarray.DataArray (sample: 4, y: 6, delta: 3)>
array([[[18,  4, 81],
        [74, 38, 78],
        [66, 82, 34],
        [47, 60,  8],
        [21, 44, 56],
        [72, 16, 72]],

       [[58, 57, 80],
        [56, 17, 17],
        [61, 83, 87],
        [ 3, 53, 48],
        [46, 49, 20],
        [97, 96,  3]],

       [[ 8, 73, 79],
        [20, 89, 16],
        [70, 39, 60],
        [32, 52, 49],
        [41, 79, 19],
        [91, 25, 40]],

       [[39, 11, 15],
        [78, 55, 20],
        [78, 43, 31],
        [92, 50, 91],
        [44, 61, 27],
        [79, 16, 39]]])
Coordinates:
  * sample   (sample) |S2 'n1' 'n2' 'n3' 'n4'
  * delta    (delta) |S2 'dx' 'dy' 'dz'
Dimensions without coordinates: y
```

Answer (score 1):

```
tmp[0][0] = np.zeros(3)
tmp[3][:, 2] = np.ones(6)

[[[ 0  0  0]
  [13 17 33]
  [61 97  6]
  [29 43 37]
  [ 5 36 21]
  [31 85 55]]

 [[69 92 69]
  [61 63 45]
  [10 58 56]
  [30 53  9]
  [10 83 95]
  [23 19 71]]

 [[88 83 26]
  [ 1  1 34]
  [ 7 80  2]
  [46 47 55]
  [ 5 22 63]
  [40 76 37]]

 [[54 15  1]
  [95 41  1]
  [61 43  1]
  [88 69  1]
  [45 51  1]
  [21 57  1]]]
```

Comment: Is it possible to achieve the same by using coordinate names?

Comment: @user2958481 I'm not familiar with xarray but it seems xarray based on numpy according to documentation. Anyway the answer is yes, please check look up syntax table on the link page(http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/indexing.html).

Answer (score 0):

```
tmp[0][0] = [0,0,0] # updates first row to [0,0,0]

for x in range(len(tmp[3])): # update last column
    tmp[3][x][2] = 1
```